# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: javascript, css

Есть вот такой код. Инспектор выдаёт такую вот ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Не могу понять в чём дело. Вроде же есть проверка и по идее, если нет таких переменных, то код не должен же выполняться?

```
var headerTitleText = document.querySelectorAll(".header-title_text");
var headerImg = document.querySelectorAll(".header-img");

setTimeout(function (){
if(headerImg && headerTitleText){
    headerTitleText[0].style.opacity = "1",
    headerImg[0].style.opacity = "1"
}}, 500);
```

Comment: То, что он есть, не означает что он массив, и у него есть нулевой элемент. Он вполне может быть пустым массивом ( а ещё точнее NodeList)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) **всегда** возвращает [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), поэтому в проверке

```
headerImg && headerTitleText
```

нет смысла. Вместо этого нужно проверять, что в данных коллекциях есть элементы, для этого можно проверить `length`

```
if(headerImg.length && headerTitleText.length){
```